Fixing Bathroom Fan
The fan in my bathroom stopped spinning. It just makes a humming noise and gets hot. I took it out. I cleaned as much of the dust off it as I could. I tried putting 3 in 1 oil where the shaft connects to the fan and the motor. That didn't fix it. So, I sprayed WD-40 in it. That didn't fix it. So, I tried silicone spray. That didn't help, either. The motor is a Fasco 7163-1944 Type U63. The motor is available for purchase online, and I'm ok with buying a new one. The problem is that it's in a fan housing. I tried removing the housing with my hands, but it won't budge. Is is safe to pry the fan off the shaft with a crowbar or something? I'm guessing I'll have to re-use this housing unless someone knows where I can buy a new one. Here are some photos:




Look inside the fan where the motor shaft connects to the fan. There should be an Allen screw or a small slotted screw opposite the flat edge of the motor shaft as shown on the back of the fan. You'll probably have to go through the blades with your Allen wrench or screwdriver to get to the screw. Loosen the screw and pull the fan off. Don't try to force it off with a crowbar or you'll bend the housing and it will be difficult to reinstall it.
